# ¿Cómo utilizar atributos de clases hijas en la clase padre en Python?

Tags: python, poo, clase

El ejercicio es con programación orientada a objetos, por lo que se deben usar clases. Consiste en lo siguiente: Se debe crear un **drone** que posea batería, número de serie, estado de encendido o apagado, latitud y longitud, **altímetro**,**GPS** y un **motor**. (Lo que se encuentra en negrita son las clases que se deben crear). Cada dispositivo tiene una marca de fabricante. El *GPS* posee dos atributos adicionales a la marca; latitud y longitud, los cuales son obtenidos con números aleatorios entre -90 y 90. El *altímetro* posee un atributo adicional; indicador de altura, obtenido tambien de forma aleatoria con valores entre 1 y 200. Y finalmente el *motor* posee adicional un indicador de revoluciones, además el motor puede apagarse, encenderse, entre otras opciones, lo que modifica las revoluciones pero esto no es relevante.

Mi pregunta es, cómo hago para modificar los atributos de las clases *Altimetro, GPS y Motor* para poder utilizarlos en la clase padre; *Drone*. Ejemplo, el *Drone* posee la función de activar, cuando esto sucede se debe consultar al *GPS* para que brinde la latitud y longitud y de esta forma hacer el set de latitud y longitud en la clase *Drone*.

Adjunto código que tengo hasta el momento, el error que muestra es que GPS no está definido.

```
import random

def aleatorioAltimetro():
    return random.randint(1,200)
def aleatorioGPS():
    return random.randint(-90,90)

class Drone:
    def __init__(self,pBateria=1600):

    self.__bateria=pBateria
    self.__numeroSerie="FCN16"
    self.__estado="Apagado"
    self.__latitud=0
    self.__longitud=0

    #Get
   def getBateria(self):
       return self.__bateria
   def getNumeroSerie(self):
       return self.__numeroSerie
   def getEstado(self):
       return self.__estado
   def getLatitud(self):
       return self.__latitud    
   def getLongitud(self):
       return self.__longitud

   #Set
   def setBateria(self,pNuevaBateria):
       self.__bateria=pNuevaBateria
   def setNumeroSerie(self,pSerie):
       self.__numeroSerie=pSerie
   def setEstado(self,pNuevoEstado):
       self.__estado=pNuevoEstado
   def setLatitud(self,pNuevaLatitud):
       self.__latitud=pNuevaLatitud
   def setLongitud(self,pNuevaLongitud):
       self.__longitud=pNuevaLongitud

   def activar(self):
       self.__latitud=GPS.getLatitud()
       self.__longitud=GPS.getLongitud()

#Clases

class Altimetro(Drone):
   def __init__(self):
       self.__marcaAltimetro="Sony"
       self.__altitud=aleatorioAltimetro()

   #Get
   def getMarcaAltimetro(self):
       return self.__marcaAltimetro
   def getAltitud(self):
       return self.__altitud

   #Set
   def setMarcaAltimetro(self,pNuevaMarcaA):
       self.__marcaAltimetro=pNuevaMarcaA
   def setAltitud(self,pNuevaAltura):
       self.__altitud=pNuevaAltura

class GPS(Drone):
   def __init__(pLatitud=aleatorioGPS(),pLongitud=aleatorioGPS()):
       self.__marcaGPS="Yamaha"
       self.__latitud=pLatitud
       self.__longitud=pLongitud

#Get
   def getMarcaGPS(self):
       return self.__marcaGPS
   def getLatitud(self):
       return self.__latitud
   def getLongitud(self):
       return self.__longitud

#Set
   def setMarcaGPS(self,pNuevaMarcaG):
       self.__marcaGPS=pNuevaMarcaG
   def setLatitud(self,pNuevaLatitud):
       self.__latitud=pNuevaLatitud
   def setLongitud(self,pNuevaLongitud):
       self.__longitud=pNuevaLongitud

class Motor(Drone):
    def __init__(self,pRevoluciones):
       self.__marcaMotor="Samsung"
       self.__revoluciones=pRevoluciones

   #Get
   def getMarcaMotor(self):
       return self.__marcaMotor
   def getRevoluciones(self):
       return self.__revoluciones

#Set
   def setMarcaMotor(self,pNuevamarcaM):
       self.__marcaM=pNuevaMarca
   def setRevoluciones(self,pNuevasRevoluciones):
       self.__revoluciones=pNuevasRevoluciones

   def apagar():
       self.setRevoluciones(0)
   def encender():
       self.setRevoluciones(10)
   def estabilizar():
       self.setRevoluciones(1100)
   def ascender():
      self.setRevoluciones(1400)
   def descender():
       self.setRevoluciones(725)
```

`

Comment: Creo que la relación de herencia deberia ser inversa, un Motor no usa un Drone ni debe tener las propiedades de este, es un Drone el que usa un Motor. De todas formas, a no ser que que obliguen a usar herencia este caso es un ejemplo claro de **composición**, un Drone **tiene** un motor, un GPS y un altímetro. El verbo clave en la herencia es más bién "ser" y no "tener".

Comment: @FJSevilla Sí me obligan a usar herencia y de hecho en la evaluación dice que hay que crear 3 clases adicionales a Drone, y cada una debe tener lo que especifiqué. Y también en la evaluación pide poner como atributos en la clase Drone a motor, gps y altímetro.
Si me ayudaras a saber cómo hacerlo sería genial

Comment: Lo ideal es construir tres clases y dentro de Drone creas  3 atributos instanciando Motor, GPS y altímetro. Tenemos 4 clases, cada Drone tiene su motor, su GPS y su altímetro propio pero no hay herencia aquí. Usar herencia aquí es forzar las cosas... pero bueno. En todo caso la herencia debe ser Drone heredando de motor, gps, y altímetro y no al revés. Si altímetro hereda de Drone implica que altímetro es un Drone, esto no tiene sentido. Si de verdad te espesifican que use herencia (que no es lo mismo que usar 4 clases distintas) no entiendo lo de los atributos...

Comment: Repito, lo lógico son cuatro clases y crear los atributos Motor, GPS y Altímetro instanciando sus clases correspondientes dentro de la clase Drone. Pero bueno, a veces fuerzan tanto las cosas con las tareas que pierden sentido en la vida real... XD

Comment: Lo único que tendría sentido es si le piden crear un clase Drone básica que solo tenga motor, y crear clases para Drones más avanzados uno que tengan GPS, otro que tenga altímetro y otro que tenga ambos.